# Part of proof of Prime Number Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, prime-numbers

If $x\ge 1$, let $\pi(x) = \sum_{p\le x} 1$ denote the number of primes $\le x$. The prime number theorem states that $\pi(x) \sim {x\over \log(x)}$

This is usually proved by studying the related function $\theta (x)=\sum_{p\le x} \log (p)$. I want to show that the prime number theorem is equivalent to the relation $\theta(x) \sim x$.

I already derived the following equation: 
$$\theta(x)= \pi(x)\log(x)-\int_{x}^2 {\pi(t)\over t}dt $$
$$\pi(x)={\theta(x)\over \log(x)} + \int_{x}^2 {\theta(t)\over {t \log^2t}}dt$$
It is also known that $\theta(x) \sim x$, i.e. $\lim_{x\to \infty}{ {\theta(x)\over x}}=1$, and $$\int_{x}^2{1\over \log(y)} dy={x\over \log(x)} + o({x\over \log(x)})$$

I also derived: $$\int_{x}^2{1\over \log^2(y)}dy = \textrm{Li}(x) - {x\over \log(x)} + {2\over \log(2)}$$, where $Li(x) = \int_{x}^2 {dt\over \log(t)}$, $o$ is the Hardy's little o notation.

Assuming these pieces of information, I'm having trouble establishing the prime number theorem. Could someone complete the proof please? Thanks.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\theta(x)}x = 1$ implies that for any $m,M$ with $0 < m < 1 < M, mx < \theta(x) < Mx$ once $x$ is sufficiently large. Plug that into the integral in your equation for $\pi(x)$ in terms of $\theta(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that $$\pi\left(x\right)\sim\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}
 $$ we have, by [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula), $$\theta\left(x\right)=\pi\left(x\right)\log\left(x\right)-\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\pi\left(t\right)}{t}dt\sim x-\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log\left(t\right)}\sim x-\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}
 $$ and so $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\theta\left(x\right)}{x}=1.
 $$ Now if we assume $$\theta\left(x\right)\sim x
 $$ we have, using again the Abel's summation, $$\pi\left(x\right)=\frac{\theta\left(x\right)}{\log\left(x\right)}+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\theta\left(t\right)}{t\log^{2}\left(t\right)}dt\sim\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log^{2}\left(t\right)}=\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)+\frac{2}{\log\left(2\right)}\sim\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}.$$